# Як перекласти "merge code"

Tags: переклад, from-english, терміни

Є такі варіанти:

> *noun*
>   поглинання, поглинення, пожирання.
>   *verb*
>   1 гуртувати, з'єднати, з'єднувати, згуртовувати, згуртувати, об'єднати, об'єднувати, поєднати, поєднувати, сполучати, єднати.
>   2 домішувати, змішати, змішувати.
>   3 з'єднати, з'єднувати, об'єднати, об'єднувати, переплітати, сполучати, єднати.
>   4 з'єднувати, зливати, злити, поглинати, сполучати, єднати.
>   5 заволодівати, поглинати.
>   6 зварювати, згаснути, плавити, розчиняти, сплавляти.
>   7 комбінувати, об'єднати, об'єднувати, поєднати.
>   8 об'єднувати, поєднувати, уніфікувати

http://slovnenya.com/dictionary/merge

Поки що мій фаворит - 'я хочу домішати новий код в головну гілку проекту'

Comment: не певен, що ви домішуєте саме код, адже гілка може містити багато іншої інформації, наприклад, зображення, базу даних тощо.

Comment: Домішати - це дуже, ДУЖЕ поганий переклад. Кажу це як програміст і людина із гарною англійською. Потрібно підмітити, код не мерджать, мерджать гілки зі змінами в коді в системах контролю версій. Під цим розуміють застосування змін із однієї гілки в іншу таким чином, що ті зміни стають присутніми в обох гілках, злиття змін.

Comment: @improbable термін merge в комп'ютерній термінології з'явився ще коли необхідно було робити merge data в базах даних, тому справді, "домішати" не найкращий варіант перекладу.

Я погоджуюся для перекладу терміну merge було б більш доречно використовувати варіанти, які були запропоновані в коментарях - "об'єднати" або "зростити" гілки проекту.

Comment: @JabbyPanda Ніколи не чув, щоб хтось казав merge data в базах даних і я працюю в індустрії. Дані вносять, вставляють, мігрують, але не зливають. Про мене, найкращий варіант - "злиття" і слово дуже добре передає про що іде мова(див. 2 значення https://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=36551&page=1152)

Comment: У *мішати* є ще перевага звукової подібності до *мержити*.

Comment: @AndriyIvanchenko Правильно, всі коміти(зміни) із однієї гілки зливаються/об'єднуються зі комітами(змінами) поточної/цільової гілки. Але гілки зміни якої зливаються не отримує змін гілки в яку зливають, тому слово merge, можливо, не дуже гарно передає суть процесу однак саме це слово вживається в гіті(система контролю версій).

Comment: @impobable 

команда MERGE в SQL
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Домішати можна абищо новачка у воду, зрощують зазвичай  кістки, а Code Flow! Ви бачили як виглядає, коли application продукує код? Він саме тече по екрану у віконці термінала :)

Comment: Див. також [тут](//chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115766).

Answer (score 7):

### **Злиття коду** | **Об'єднання (гілок) коду** | **Інтеграція змін до коду**

**[Злиття](https://uk.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%82%D1%8F)** — об'єднання двох різних об'єктів в одне ціле таким чином, що утворюється єдиний об'єкт з єдиними властивостями. Наприклад, [**Злиття Даних**](https://uk.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%82%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85).

**Злиття** - це багатоетапний процес, який спочатку вимагає об’єднати колективні дані про елементи на одній сторінці (елемент одержувача), і, нарешті, призведе до переспрямування застарілої сторінки до одержувача. [Help:Merge](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Help:Merge)

> [**Merge (version control)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(version_control)) у контролі версій **злиття** (також зване
> **[інтеграцією](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_integration)**) — це фундаментальна операція, яка узгоджує численні
> зміни, внесені до набору файлів, керованих версіями. Найчастіше це
> необхідно, коли файл змінюється в двох **незалежних гілках** і згодом
> **об’єднується**. Результатом є єдина колекція файлів, яка містить обидва
> набори змін.

> [**Merge**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(SQL)) — оператор мови SQL, який дозволяє **об'єднати** дані однієї
> таблиці з даними іншої таблиці. При **злитті** таблиць перевіряється відповідність
> умові, і якщо значення істинне, то виконується Update, а якщо ні -
> Insert.

> **[Git merge](https://www.atlassian.com/ru/git/tutorials/using-branches/git-merge)** **(злиття)** використовується в **Git**, щоб зібрати воєдино розгалужену історію. Команда [git merge](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) виконує злиття окремих
> напрямків розробки, створених за допомогою команди git branch, в єдину
> гілку.

**[Merging code](https://www.perforce.com/blog/vcs/merging-code-how-automate-it)** **(злиття коду)** є важливим аспектом розробки програмного забезпечення. Злиття коду дозволяє декільком розробникам програмного забезпечення **інтегрувати зміни** у свою кодову базу. Розробники починають цей процес з відгалуження від спільної лінії коду, яку часто називають [основною гілкою](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branching_(version_control)). Потім, коли робота буде завершена та перевірена, відгалужена **гілка буде об’єднана** з основною (інтегрована назад до спільної бази коду).

Слід зауважити, що історично [**Merge**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(software)) походить від програмного забезпечення, яке дозволяло запускати найперші системи Windows та DOS в операційній системі UNIX. Згодом, це поняття поширилося і стало загальновживаним в багатьох сферах IT, а в системах контролю версій  перетворилося в назву ідентичної команди **merge**.

### Висновок:

Отже, на мою думку, найбільш точним перекладом фрази **merge code** буде **злиття коду**, але вжиток **об'єднання коду** (у значенні "об'єднання гілок коду") та **інтеграція коду** (у значенні "інтеграція змін до бази коду") також є цілком обгрунтованим і не є помилковим. Такі форми перекладу слід вживати відповідно до контексту речення, якщо цього вимагає стилістика.

Comment: Образ саме такий. Гілки саме зливаються, як річки, `merge` застосовується і до річок також. І далі два незалежні потоки (наприклад, часові потоки, як гілки в `git`), зливаються в один і далі йдуть разом.

Comment: А звідки це зображення, якщо не секрет? (Тобто, я так розумію, Ви наводите дані з якогось словника — але варто вказати з якого.)

Comment: Не дуже зрозуміло, що ви хотіли показати перекладом за посередництва російської.

Comment: `не єдине ціле, а сукупність гілок з можливістю подальшого роз'єднання` - це твердження потребує доказів. 
В git утворюється самє єдине ціле. А те. що можна повернутися назад у часі і відтворити момент до злиття - це функція системи контролю версій, і якісних її аналогій у фізичному світі і літературній мові ви не знайдете.

Comment: @RomanMikhol чи можете надати твердження щодо того, же: а) російська є найближчою за семантичними ознаками, б) це входе в 98 %, а не 2 %.

Comment: @RomanMikhol Не працює злиття. Не вдається застосувати це слово. Об'єднання - так, інтеграція - можливо. Злиття - в смітник.

Comment: @AndriyIvanchenko, так прямо ж у своїй відповіді і наводжу приклади, як вживати цей термін у реченні за для запобігання повторів інших)) "|" - це оператор логіки "або".

Comment: "Злиття" - це як зі "вподобайкою". Слово наче використовують, але коли дивишся відео від філологів, то замість "ставте вподобайки" вони використовують правильне значення "вподобайте наше відео". Тобто використати слово "злиття" може десь і можна десь в коморі, але терміном воно не може бути, бо не клеїться до змісту.

Answer (score 5):

**merge code**

Визначимо спочатку значення слів.

> **[Code](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/code)** - a language used to program (= give instructions to) computers.
>
> **[Merge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/merge)** - to combine or join together, or to cause things to do this.

Отже code - це певна мова, певний набір наказів. Алгоритм дій описаний певною мовою. Тобто дослівно щось схоже на "**об'єднати накази**".

Але усе змінює вказаний приклад: "я хочу домішати новий **код в головну гілку проекту**". По суті приклад описаний не зовсім точно.

Інформаційні технології - це переважно подібність до навколишнього середовища чи до інших галузей.

#### Правильний переклад

Справа в тому, що в прикладі описується подібність з деревом. Можливо технологія GIT. А дії з деревом вже давно визначені. Що роблять з гілками для об'єднання? - зрощують. Тобто правильно використовувати "**зростити гілки**" щодо вказаного прикладу.

Під час зрощування гілок ви маєте два набори команд, два алгоритми, які об'єднуються в один. Або ж ви об'єднуєте коди, якщо слово наказ суперечить вашій ідеології.

В [прикладі](https://git-scm.com/book/uk/v2/%D0%93%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D0%B2-git-%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8-%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F) опису подібних дій можна чітко побачити, що до нового набору наказів застосовують commit, а до гілок - merge. Тобто хоча і можна сказати merge code, але напряму виконати дію об'єднання (merge) наборів наказів (code) в гілку в подібних технологіях без попередній підготовчих дій неможливо.

#### Чому не можна використовувати слово мішати?

Джерело Великий тлумачний словник української мови. Бусел. 2005.

> **Мішати** - сполучати що-небудь різнорідне. Після перемішування
> порушується порядок розташування чого-небудь.

В даному випадку набір наказів має певний порядок, який не можна порушувати. Навіть під час зрощення гілок накази мають своє певне місце, порядок, зміна якого призведе до неочікуваного алгоритму дій.

#### Чому не можна зливати гілки?

> [**Зливати**](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8) - Об'єднуючи кого-, що-небудь із кимсь, чимсь, створювати одне
> ціле.

Тобто результатом зливання є об'єднання, що створює єдине ціле з того, що злили. В даному випадку зливають гілки. (і це дуже дивно, як можна гілку злити?, це ж не рідина). Але результатом зрощення гілок є створення місця зрощення а не єдиної суцільної гілки.

Comment: Можна зливати компанії, але вони теж не рідина.

Comment: @VictorSergienko  Злиття компанії створює єдине ціле. Об'єднання гілок не зливає гілки в єдине ціле, а створює лише місце з'єднання, місце зрощення. Гілки до місця з'єднання залишаються присутні. Якщо знищити місце з'єднання, то гілки нікуди не зникнуть. Після об'єднання компаній буде важко роз'єднати їх до попередніх станів. Так само як і рідини. Коли ви зливаєте рідини до купи, то вам важко буде роз'єднати їх окремо. Але щодо об'єднання компаній я б теж не використовував слово злити, адже злиття не передбачає досягнення якогось порядку. Але ж компанії об'єднують за певним порядком.

Comment: @VictorSergienko Якщо враховувати, що термін "злити компанії" якимось чином прийшов до нас з Англії, то я переконаний, що це черговий ляп в перекладі. Адже для злиття рідин використовують слово combine, а термін пішов від слова merge.

Comment: І даремно. Company merger - давній термін, а гілки в гіті позначають не фізичне дерево, а дерево часу. Два паралельні часові потоки, які потім зливаються і далі продовжуються як одне ціле. Дніпро і Самара зливаються, і теж нікуди з мапи не зникають.

Comment: @VictorSergienko Річки не зливаються. Вони не можуть самі себе злити. Вони утворюють гирло. Одна річка може впадати в іншу, або якось інакше. Якщо річки злити, то це означає, що одна з річок зникає і в результаті створюють нове об'єднання.

Comment: @VictorSergienko "а гілки в гіті позначають не фізичне дерево, а дерево часу" Основою цього є подібність до дерева і його особливостей.

Comment: Ви маєте право на власну ментальну модель гіта, річки і мови. Чи переконає вас доведення того, що річки можуть зливатися, а а гілки дерева роблять не merge, а graft (теж є терміном гіта)?

Comment: @VictorSergienko Мені цікаво. Але якщо я правильно зрозумів, то ваші слова лише закріпили мою точку зору. Бо graft - це прищепа. Функція та дії узгоджені з щепленням до гілки дерева іншої гілки. Все збігається. Не розумію супротиву проти мого пояснення суті речей.

Comment: Перепрошую, але результатом зливання є наново наповнений водою бачок унітаза. А результатом злиття, так, є саме об'єднання.

Comment: Дякую, я знаю, як працює git merge. Саме зараз я в своїй компанії вхожу в експертну групу. А ось з вашої послідовності технічно неточних тверджень мені здається, що ви не дуже розумієте предмет. Ви побудували власну ментальну модель (занадто ускладнену, як на мене) і захищаєте її. Подальше обговорення вважаю недоцільним, свій голос я подав.

Comment: Ви робите неправильний висновок з документації, бо ви його робите не з самого прикладу, скільки з власних дилетантських теорій. Та і зрощують не гілки між собою, а одну зламану чи відрізану гілку, як зламану кістку, наприклад. В садівництві нема терміну для двох гілок, які зрощують, щоб утворити кільце, як в прикладі, це садівницький нонсенс. Наша група розмовляє лише англійською і не займається перекладами.

Comment: Мабуть, ваша теорія заслуговує окремого розбору, бо аж 5 людей знайшли її вартою голосу. 
Напишу і опублікую.

Comment: Ось [я натайпив статтю](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1acTUSlN2BvruqFercAVXoY-AmX-RHzup6Pzp741GldI/edit).
Тож, що я зроблю. 1. Я за день-два видалю свої останні 3 коментарі, бо comments are not for extended discussion. 2. @AndriyIvanchenko, я пропоную вам прочитати статю, обмислити її десь дні зо три (раніше не треба), і переробити свою відповідь. Якщо ви не погодитися з аргументацією, я опублікую статтю на сайті спеціалістів dou.ua, і хай вони голосуванням вирішать, хто правий. Якщо замінусують мене — ну що ж, я програю цю суперечку.

Comment: Розширив параграф про "зрощування" у відгуку. На жаль, продовжувати дискусію тут буде проти правил SE, з кожним новим коментарем ми ризикуємо, що робот перетворить їх на чат. Що я можу зробити - це написати ще одну альтернативну відповідь, теж у форматі "чому інші відповіді неправильні, а ця правильна". Це вже за пару днів, мабуть.

Comment: Зростити можна гілки живого дерева, мертвого - ніт.

Answer (score 4):

Мені подобається Ваш варіант:

> Я хочу **домішати** новий код в головну гілку проекту.

Але на практиці, мені здається, перемагатимуть очевидніші (у тому сенсі, що вони, мабуть, першими згадуватимуться тим, хто читає англійське *merge*) ***об'єднувати***, ***зливати***.

Зокрема:

- [база термінів Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/language/Search?searchTerm=merge&langID=799&Source=true&productid=0) — *об'єднати*, *злиття*, *злити*;
- [переклади KDE](https://l10n.kde.org/team-infos.php?teamcode=uk) (зокрема [переклад kdesvn](https://websvn.kde.org/trunk/l10n-kf5/uk/messages/extragear-sdk/kdesvn.po?view=markup)) — *об'єднання*, *об'єднувати*, *об'єднати*;
- див. також [словники на E2U](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=merge&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on).

Хоча у випадку, коли варто відрізняти джерело від місця призначення (*merge A to B*) Ваш варіант має велику перевагу.

Answer (score 3):

[e2u](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=merge&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on) подає:

> <sub>Англійсько-український словник з математики та інформатики 2010 (Є. Мейнарович, М. Кратко)</sub> 
> **merge command** = кома́нда "об’єдна́ти", кома́нда об’є́днування
>
> <sub>Англійсько-українсько-англійський словник наукової мови (фізика та споріднені науки). Частина І (О. Кочерга, Є. Мейнарович)</sub>
> **to merge files** об’є́днувати фа́йли

Отже, можна *об'єднати гілки*. Але залишається питання з тим як вказати в якій гілці опиниться результат. Щоб це однозначно вказати можна використати слово **вплести**. Наприклад:

> *Вплести гілку `feature` в гілку `develop`.*

Comment: @AndriyIvanchenko Я сказав би навпаки - дані з обох гілок в результаті - результовній гілці, але одна з гілок залишається незмінною. Мені *вплести* більше подобається ніж *вростити*. І, через те, що merge зберігає всю інформацію, то можна і *розплести* чи *виплести*. Утворити подібні дієслова від *зростити* не дуже виходить.

Comment: Про історію, якщо ви маєте гілку отриману в результаті merge, то ви можете відновити дві оригінальні гілки. І мати слова для цього було б добре. Англійською я б мабуть сказав unmerge. А от зі *зростити* нічого вдалого не виходить придумати.

Comment: Абсолютно згодний, що merge стосовно files і commands краще і семантично правильно перекласти, як об'єднання файлів, команд.

Answer (score 0):

**merge code** - стулити код

> [Стуляти](http://sum.in.ua/s/stuljaty) - наближаючи впритул одне до одного, щільно з'єднувати
>   (предмети або краї предметів)

Comment: Зазвичай, спочатку просять: "тихіше, будь ласка" і якщо не зрозуміло, застосовують гпубощі: "стули пельку". :)

Answer (score 0):

Якщо мова йде про код, то merge code - об'єднати код.

Якщо мова йде про 'я хочу домішати новий код в головну гілку проекту', то краще сказати "я хочу додати зміни до коду в головну гілку проєкту".

Якщо мова йде про merge branches - то зростити (об'єднати) гілки. Згідно наявній тут відповіді user1677.

Без джерел.

Comment: Застосування виразу «Об'єднання коду» також семантично вірне і його не слід вважати помилковим.